# Will only show the first 10 wordpress posts instead of all my posts

Tags: loop

I have a page that is supposed to show all of my portfolio posts but it only shows the first 10, I have no idea why

```
<div class="row">

          <?php
            $args = array( 
              'post_type' => 'portfolio'
            );
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

          ?>

          <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

          <div class="col-xs-3 portfolio-piece">
              <h3 style="color:#1B7B98; text-align:center;">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
              </h3>

              <?php

                $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(); 
                $thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'thumbnail-size', true );
              ?>

              <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $thumbnail_url[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title();?> graphic"></a></p>


          </div>

          <?php $portfolio_count = $the_query->current_post + 1; ?>
          <?php if ( $portfolio_count % 4 == 0): ?>

          </div><div class="row">

          <?php endif; ?>


          <?php endwhile; endif; ?>


        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your following array

```
 $args = array( 
              'post_type' => 'portfolio'
            );
```

Use your array like this

```
 $args = array( 
                  'post_type' => 'portfolio',
                  'posts_per_page' => -1  //It will display all of your posts
                );
```